# JavasScript alert() Angular 2 simple equivalent?

Tags: javascript, angular, alert

I need to display an alert box when clicking on a div. In pure JavaScript (vanilla.js) this would be

```
alert("message displayed");
```

How would I do that in Angular2 in the most simple way possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same in angular as well.Since [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is a global object and is accessible directly in your class

```
alert("message displayed");
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxkkeq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: OMG, I forgot I could use js in ts .Tnx!!

Comment: I already voted, just waiting for the time to pass so I'm able to +15 it

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing build-in in Angular 2+. 
Very popular plugin is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-toastr if you don't want the ugliness of `window.alert()` :)